# Where do I find all the Eggos?

Tags: stranger-things-the-game

I can't find the last Eggo, number 8. How do I collect every Eggo in the game?

Comment: See https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/319254/where-can-i-find-every-gnome for finding the other ones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to posts in [this megathread](https://www.reddit.com/r/StrangerThings/comments/74cbz5/stranger_things_the_game_discussion/), the only two Eggos that aren't obtained from defeating bosses are the one in Wheeler's refrigerator and the one you find by breaking a wall in Bradley's Big Buy store.

> - ALL EGGOS – 1-6 by defeating bosses
> - 1 In the Wheelers Fridge
> - 1 In the cracked wall in the big buy store

---

> The only two Eggos not obtained from defeating bosses (1-6) are the one in the Wheeler's fridge (7) and the one found by breaking the wall inside Bradley's Big Buy store (8).

Based on the second quote, it looks like the Eggo you're missing is the one behind the breakable wall in the Big Buy store.

Answer (score -4):

I found the eggo number 8 inside the store Big Bradley's

Comment: This doesn't add anything that isn't already in the accepted answer.