# Where can I find every gnome?

Tags: stranger-things-the-game

No matter where I look, I just can't find gnome number [insert number here]. Where can I find every gnome in the game?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Gnomes locations:

> 1. Behind Hopper's Cabin
> 2. In Forest Dungeon (East of entrance through pipes)
> 3. In Jungle between Lab and Quarry
> 4. In Jungle South of School
> 5. In School (Northwest)
> 6. In Corn Field
> 7. In Jungle West of Sewers
> 8. In Lab (Go through pipes in room Northeast of entrance)
> 9. In Sewers (First Room)
> 10. In Library (Eastern Room from entrance)
> 11. In House South of Graveyard
> 12. In Quarry (Southeast past bear)

Source: [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AaFLUxtoCoTNxed2US3rG52oXMbQsC_zeFCYq8F8wzc/edit#gid=0) from [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/StrangerThings/comments/74cbz5/stranger_things_the_game_discussion/).

And this is [video guide](https://youtu.be/VPVCVeLF5xU).